# Get next available date in Pandas filter by day

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, datetime64

I have filtered the `datetime64[ns]` type in pandas dataframe to get data that falls on specific date of each month using the following line of code.

```
df[df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.day) == 1]
```

The output is as follows:

```
19.9    2013-07-01
34.8    2013-08-01
12.9    2013-10-01
12.6    2013-11-01
```

But if you notice the entry for `2013-09-01` is missing as it is not available in the original dataset. In such situation I want to get data for `2013-09-02`. Ideally if a date falls on weekend (Saturday and Sunday or any missing date like holidays or data not available for specific date), I want to get the data for the next available date. Wondering if we can achieve using pandas or I need to manually iterate over perform this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `DatetimeIndex` with [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) and `method='bfill'` for back filling missing values:

```
df = df.set_index('Date').asfreq('d', method='bfill')
```

Then filter by [`DatetimeIndex.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day.html):

```
df1 = df[df.index.day == 1]
```

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
    Val       Date
0  19.9 2013-07-01
1  34.8 2013-08-01
2  10.4 2013-09-02
3  12.9 2013-10-01
4  12.6 2013-11-01

print (df.dtypes)
Val            float64
Date    datetime64[ns]

df = df.set_index('Date').asfreq('d', method='bfill')
df1 = df[df.index.day == 1]
print (df1)
             Val
Date            
2013-07-01  19.9
2013-08-01  34.8
2013-09-01  10.4
2013-10-01  12.9
2013-11-01  12.6
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach even makes day wise accessing easy instead of using lambda expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can also do so by setting the date as the index and searching for the next existing date to the first day of each month using [index.get_loc()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and set method to be **bfill**:

```
print(df)
             Val
Date            
2013-07-01  19.9
2013-08-01  34.8
2013-08-02  34.8
2013-09-02  10.4
2013-10-01  12.9
2013-11-01  12.6

df = df.set_index('Date')
df.iloc[[df.index.get_loc(datetime.datetime(date[0],date[1],1),
                   method='bfill') for date,_ in df.groupby(
                   [df.index.year,df.index.month])]]

             Val
Date            
2013-07-01  19.9
2013-08-01  34.8
2013-09-02  10.4
2013-10-01  12.9
2013-11-01  12.6
```